# How to resolve jQuery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keyup

I have a jQuery custom file which is disabling or conflicting my other jQuery file, please how do i resolve this. Please see below:
My Custom file:

```
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});
```

Conflicting Files:

```
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
```

I would be more than happy if this is resolved.

Comment: Can't find any conflicting files. Are you sure?

Comment: Are u useing two diffrent versions of Jquery??

Comment: I just edited, the conflicting files are visible now

Comment: And what do you mean by conflict? Is isotope not working as expected or nprogress one???

Comment: I noticed the "keyup(function() " at the top of my custom file in $(".search").keyup(function() is exactly what is disabling the other files. When i remove the function(), the other files works fine but my custom file won't work and i want both to work as they do different thing. Any help please?

Comment: Maybe because you are setting `#result` content using `html()` method which removes any previous data/events bound to any descendant element. BUT still you didn't clearly explain WHAT doesn't work???

Comment: Or it could be because you are stopping event propagation using in handler `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you know for certain jQuery is conflicting - you've checked the console errors, etc.

You could wrap your jQuery in a self-executing anonymous function as follows:

```
(function($) { 
  $(".search").keyup(function() 
  { 
  var searchid = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
  if(searchid!='')
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
       {
         $("#result").html(html).show();
       }
     });
   }return false;    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT - a bit of explanation of what's happened above. In order to prevent any potential conflicts with other scripts / frameworks we are passing the jQuery object as an argument to our function (hence `function($)`). The benefits of doing this is that you can now use `$` locally within the function at will. Without fear of conflicting with other scripts on a `global` scope.

Comment: Issue seems not related to mutliple included jQuery versions but related to ajax reloaded content

Comment: @A.Wolff I think you're probably right. At the time of writing my original answer, I was assuming the OP had checked the console errors - hence why he said it was a standard multiple jQuery / script conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to fix the problem by just wrapping it with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
//-----
});
```